# docdokuplm post-installation instructions

Tags: linux, installation, plm, payara

## docdokuplm

Hi !

Just checking out your PLM, looks great!  I followed your instructions:
https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-plm/wiki/Installation-Guide

I used the nightly build.

After uploading the ear file and then using http://localhost:8080 I see the Payara server page.  Was there something else I need todo or where do I start to troubleshoot?  Thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to have come to the wrong place.  This is not the support forum for that product.

Comment: " Thanks for using DocDokuPLM.  As an unsubscribed user you should ask your question on https://stackoverflow.com  and tag it with "docdokuplm", this is the tag we monitor. "  I don't have enough rep to create the tag

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. DocDokuPLM is not software used by programmers so questions about installing it are not on topic for this site. If the project maintainers told you to come here then they were mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

The page displayed at 8080 is the default landing page. If you have deployed the DocDokuPLM application and configured the settings detailed within the instructions, you can open the application through Payara Server. Go to `Applications` -> `DocDokuPLM` -> `Launch`, and you'll get a series of links which should help you troubleshoot.

If you can't see any, run through the installation procedure again to ensure that you haven't missed a step - it seems like there's a few steps which must be configured exactly correctly for the application to work.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this GitHub issue, this seems like a bug with DocDokuPLM](https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-plm/issues/1138). As with most software, nightly builds are inherently risky. Looking at the source, though, it seems that the code changes fairly rarely, so you might try with the previous version of Payara Server (173), though the stack traces in the GitHub issue don't look to me like an issue with Payara.

Answer (score 0):

The backend server and the UI are two separated components.
If you want to install the User Interface you have to go there :
https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-web-front

Answer (score 0):

The project which you have deployed is just for backend,inorder to interact with UI just clone the web-client from this repo https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-web-front and in command prompt use this command ***npm run dev*** then you can use this project, make sure the port number which is mentioned in ***app/webapp.properties.json*** of web-client project is same as you have given in server-config.
Read https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-web-front/wiki/Development-Guide for more details